# Direct Proof for sum of $n$ integers equation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, formal-proofs

I am trying to prove by direct proof that

> $$3+5+7+\ldots+(2n+1)=n(n+2)$$

for all natural numbers $n$. I figured out how to do it by induction, but I know it can be done directly and I can't figure out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the first term to the last.  Then the    second to the second to last.  Each pair adds to 2n+4.  There are n/2 such pairs.  Okay, I know what you are thinking.  What if n is odd?  Well that's okay too because... well there are two reasons but I've given enough of a hint.

Answer (score 7):

Do what Gauss did, reverse the sequence and add it with the original. Now each term is 2n + 4, and there are n such terms. The sum is n(2n+4). Since this results from two sequences, divide by 2 and you get the answer.

Comment: Would I reverse by starting with (2n+1) followed by (2n-1)?

Comment: @Chris Exactly, the last term becomes the first term, the second to last term becomes the second term and so on.

Comment: @Chris $(3+5+...+(2n+1)) + ((2n+1) + (2n-1) + ... + 3) = (3+2n+1) + (5 + 2n-1) + (7 + 2n - 3) + ... + (2n+1+3) = (2n+4)*n$. Divide by 2 gives $(n+2)n$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (2k+1)=2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n1=2\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+n=n(n+2)$$

where we have used the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Here is an elegant "picture proof" that $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (2i-1) = n^2$.  So you have, $\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (2i+1) = \sum_\limits{i=1}^n (2i-1) + (2n+1) - 1 = n^2 + 2n$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}1+3+5+7+\cdots+(2n-1)&=\sum_{r=1}^n (2r-1)=\sum_{r=1}^n r^2-(r-1)^2=n^2\\
3+5+7+\cdots+(\color{red}{2n}+\color{blue}1)&=\underbrace{\color{blue}1+3+5+7+\cdots+(2n-1)}_{n^2}+(\color{red}{2n})\\&=n^2+2n\\&=n(n+2)\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice trick. Note that you can directly write the second sum as a telescopic sum since $2r+1=(r+1)^2-r^2$.

Comment: @Taladris - Thanks! I realise that but wanted to show that the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers is $n^2$ using the elements that are already there.